# Not able to schedule meeting in spring -data-neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to schedule meeting for certain date with already created User in Neo4j.
When I  use the user information with meeting then it updates the user and makes the user node mostly blank which is not desired. Actually I want to keep the user id with meeting. Every things work fine but below code erased the existing user information.

Seeking help to overcome this situation.

```
if("MeetingSchedule".equalsIgnoreCase(message.getEventType())){
  Message scheduleMeeting= new Message();
  scheduleMeeting.setDatetime(LocalDate.now());
  scheduleMeeting.setMeetingDescription(message.getMeetingDescription());

  List<User> scheduledUser = message.getScheduledUser();
  List<User> addScheduledUser= new ArrayList<>();

  for(User addUserScheduled:scheduledUser) {
    User user = new User();
    Long ID= addUserScheduled.getId();
    user.setId(ID);
    addScheduledUser.add(user);
  }
  scheduleMeeting.setScheduledUser(addScheduledUser);

  return messagerepository.save(scheduleMeeting);

}
```

Code sniped in meeting class where from we have given the reference of the user as below.

```
   @Relationship(type="SCHEDULED_WITH", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
   private List<User> scheduledUser;
```

Comment: this is because you are creating new user
 User user = new User();  // See this. 
if You need to schedule with existing use so use the previously created user reference

Comment: Thanks It  gone solved. by using the existing user.